# Pivot/Transform SQL result set over time period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

Please run the below code to see the result set.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temptable

CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [VehicleKey] int, [RegistrationKey] int, [RegisteredOperatorKey] int, [StartDate] date )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 700090, 550983, 207287, N'2018-07-31T00:00:00' ), 
( 700090, 1513637, 276879, N'2018-12-31T00:00:00' ), 
( 700090, 1513637, 341604,  N'2019-02-28T00:00:00' )

SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

How do I transform the result set to look like below?

[image]

Please note the key will always be VehicleKey. Note the StartDate how records change over time for a vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the output you desire. Replace the statement `SELECT * FROM #temptable` with the code below

```
;WITH tt AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by VehicleKey ORDER BY StartDate) AS Seq
    FROM #tempTable
    )
SELECT t1.VehicleKey,
    t1.RegistrationKey As OldRegistrationKey,
    t2.RegistrationKey As NewRegistrationKey,
    t1.RegisteredOperatorKey AS OldRegisteredOperatorKey,
    t2.RegisteredOperatorKey AS NewRegisteredOperatorKey,
    t1.StartDate as OldStartDate,
    t2.StartDate as NewStartDate
FROM tt t1
INNER JOIN tt t2
    ON t1.VehicleKey = t2.VehicleKey
    AND t1.Seq = t2.Seq - 1
```